# Correct usage of the word "lack"

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, phrase-usage, email

I was writing an email yesterday which was about a rough draft of doc to be reviewed by a peer. There was just one part of the document which I thought needed improvisation.

What I wrote is →  "The only lack I feel is  ...."

After I sent the email, I realized the same sentence could have been framed better like this → "The only thing lacking in my perspective ..."

Although I try to avoid using the word "thing" within formal emails, I felt in this particular scenario, using the word "thing" would suit the purpose.

Would someone kindly appraise me if the sentence which I framed, "The only lack I feel is  ...." is grammatically correct or not?

Also, is the second sentence "The only thing lacking in my perspective ..." a correct fit to put forth my idea, or can it be framed better?

Any suggestions would be gratefully reciprocated _ /\ _

Comment: From a semantic point of view, saying "the only thing lacking in my perspective" makes no sense. How would one know? I think you are using the word *perspective* incorrectly too – your perspective is your view, and it is what it is, like say, your weight. Perhaps "**one** thing lacking in my **analysis** is..."

Comment: Or '_from_ my perspective'.